# How to download and store and then upload dropbox shared image in laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

I am trying to write a script to upload bulk product from excel sheet which contain product name, price and images. Images are the dropbox image share link.  How can I download those image from the dropbox url, save them on my server, then upload the image url to my database?

Excel sheet reading:[Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

Generic upload code:

```
public function productUpload(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('products')){
        $path= $request->file('products')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::load($path)->get();
        if($data->count()){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                //download the image create thumbain and  store to /images/product/thumbnail folder and get the link,
                $thumbnail = //here will be the path for the thumbnail

                //Original image
                $original = ;
                $data['original']= $original;
                $data['thumbnail']=$thumbnail;
                $data['name']=$value->name;
                $data['price']= $value->price;
                Product::create($data);
            }

            return redirect()->back()->with('success','Product has been uploaded');
        }
    }
}
```

<del>The image url that is in the excel sheet is like this one https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2tbsy49sraywvv/Ruby12.jpg?dl=0  This file has been removed at this point.</del>

Comment: Your link is broken.  Also, generic code isn't helpful, you need to show what you've tried, what *specifically* isn't working, and what you're trying to do.  See [ask] as well as [mcve] and also [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

You can dowload the image directly by adding dl=1 to the dropbox link [Source](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download)

And you can dowload the image to the server with the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) php command. [Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/storing-image-file-retrieved-from-external-url?page=1) and store it in the server with the Storage Facade

```
$url = "yoururl"; //check if has the dl=0 and change it to 1 or add dl=1
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$name = 'image.png';//the name of the image to store on disk.
\Storage::disk('yourdisk')->put($name, $contents);
```

Also you will get the full path to the image like this.

```
$thumbnail = storage_path('yourdir/'.$name)
```

Tested it with a file that i have on my dropbox and worked without a problem.
You still need to handle some things like errors and delays while dowloading the images.